# Get contactlis from Google in Phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins, google-contacts-api

I am trying to get user contact(email, name) list from Google in Phonegap, but getting error like:

`There was an error in your request.`

my code:

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/thin?alt=json&access_token=" + accessToken + "&max-results=500&v=3.0",
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
}).
success(function(res) {
    console.log("Success: " + JSON.stringify(res));

}).
error(function(err) {
    console.log("Error:" + err);

});
```

Comment: I tried making a request using the same URL and it works fine using cURL although there could be a difference in how the request is being constructed by `$http` than what I'm doing. Can you sniff out the raw outgoing HTTP request including headers (e.g. using the network debug tab in Chrome) and paste it here? (be sure to remove the `access_token`)

Comment: @Blake O'Hare: I am working with angularjs and phonegap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The access_token was granted without the proper API scope.

When authenticating, one of the following scopes must be included:

- Read/write: `https://www.google.com/m8/feeds`
- Read-only: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly`

Reference: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#authorizing_requests_with_oauth_20

Comment: I'm talking about whether the variable is defined. e.g. a typo earlier in the code where you set it as `var accesToken = ` or something. I'm just very suspicious because `...&access_token=undefined&...` will cause the same error message you mentioned and it's the only thing that I can't test (I already verified the other parts of the URL are correct)

Comment: check : https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/thin?alt=json&access_token=ya29.GlwLBKWcaCwiHmLx-Lz5Xl-2qougptHy_VNUs7GIJ-_tSvcG6dSJtGYySVI_48peJdRYaGrUv4Gt_Swh9GmMiJYWuDHYdidtWHrjIfNc8mXtR-9Cics4YlEoszJP6w&max-results=500&v=3.0

Comment: Okay, so I swapped out your access_token with my own (and left the rest of the request verbatim) and it works, so there is something wrong with your access_token. Get a new one?

Comment: Actually, alternative theory: are you requesting the correct API scope when getting your refresh token? e.g. `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly`
The wrong scope would generate a 401/"There was an error with your request."

Comment: so what is wrong ? because I am able to login and get it. So please help, How should I request in PhoneGap?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137813/discussion-between-blake-ohare-and-ved).

Comment: Blake O'Hare I have missed in scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly, so I added its working now. Thankyou